# PHP SQL search not returning any results

Tags: php, sql-server

I'm trying to make a search bar to search my db but it always returns 0 results,

Here is the Connect and search code,

```
<?php
  $serverName = "server";
  $connectionInfo = array( "Database"=>"server");
  $conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);
if( $conn ) {
    echo "Connection established.<br />";
  }else{
    echo "Connection could not be established.<br />";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
  }

  $output ='';

  if(isset($_POST['PartSelect'])){
    $searchq = $_POST['PartSelect'];
    $query = sqlsrv_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM Parts WHERE PartNumber LIKE '%$searchq%'") or die ("Could not search");
    $count = sqlsrv_num_rows($query);
    if($count == 0){
      $output = 'There are no results';
```

----- This Section is new error Code -----

```
            $rows = sqlsrv_has_rows( $query );
      if ($rows === true)
        echo "\nthere are rows\n";
     else
        echo "\nno rows\n";
```

---- End Section ------ 
This prints saying it has rows so it it picking up the data,

```
}
    else {
      while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($query)){
        $Partno = $row['PartNumber'];
        $output .= '<div>'.$PartNo. '</div>';
      }
 }
      ?>
```

Here is the search bar and submit button (I am using materialize as a framework), and the output at the end.

```
<form action="Tests.php" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
      <br/><input name="PartSelect" type="text" class="form-control" id="PartSelect" aria-describedby="nameHelp" placeholder="Enter Part">
      <br/><button name="SelectPartbtn" id="Submitbtn" type="Submit" class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Find</button>
    </div>

    <?php print ("$output"); ?>

  </form>
```

Comment: You are not error checking! You must test that the connection was successful and that the query was successful

Comment: Have you taken a look at your `php error log` and/or your `apache error log`

Comment: echo `$_POST['PartSelect']` or `print query and run manually in sql`

Comment: @BhargavChudasama Tried to echo $_POST['PartSelect'] and that prints fine

Comment: Try to return or echo $output after the while cicle in your php code and then call it from html code. Put out of the form the php code to print the results.

Comment: which output return when you run query manually?

Comment: I used this in SQL manually SELECT * FROM Parts WHERE PartNumber LIKE '%$searchq%' and it returned what I asked, Ive echo $searchq and that prints so I know the variable is good there.

Comment: remove `or die(....)` and instead do `if( ($errors = sqlsrv_errors() ) != null) {
        foreach( $errors as $error ) {
            echo "SQLSTATE: ".$error[ 'SQLSTATE']."<br />";
            echo "code: ".$error[ 'code']."<br />";
            echo "message: ".$error[ 'message']."<br />";
        }
    }`

Comment: @RiggsFolly No errors print so I assume the connection goes through

Comment: I ment on the query, not on the connection

Comment: @RiggsFolly same there, nothing prints

Comment: This is not your problem, but you dont have to wrap variables in quotes in statements like `<?php print ("$output"); ?>` a simple `<?php print ($output); ?>` will suffice

Comment: I just echo $query; and it prints Resource ID #5, what does this mean?

Answer (score 1):

try with this code check connection is made or not

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "username";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "myDB";

// Create connection
$conn = sqlsrv_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . sqlsrv_errors());
}
```

Comment: Used this and I have a connection